# Polygon rendering issue in map composer, QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, print-composer, rendering, qgis-2.8

Since a picture is worth a thousand words, let's go straight to the point. 
This is what I get in QGIS main window (and what I'd like to get in QGIS' map composer):

[image]

And this is what I actually get in the composer:

[image]

Note how the polygons representing the political claims (with colorized boundaries) carefully avoid the south pole in the map composer. What can I do? Googling the issue didn't help me much.

A few interesting precisions:

- The same rendering issue sometimes arises, with this dataset, in QGIS main window. I can solve it by zooming in and then zooming out. This trick doesn't work in the map composer (I tried playing with the scale, with no luck).
- When I downloaded this dataset, the "Simplify geometry" (Layer's properties > Rendering) was initially checked. Assuming this could be the cause of the issue, I unchecked it. The problem remains.

EDIT: the layer's CRS is EPSG:4326 (WGS84). It comes from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/).

Comment: What projection are you using and where did you get the data.  The fault may well lie in the original data which might have been tweaked to avoid the pole as in most non-polar coordinate systems, this would result in an infinitely long line and the data provider may not be expecting you to map to the pole itself

Comment: @MappaGnosis: that's an interesting thought. The layer is in EPSG:4326, data comes from Natural Earth. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Try turning off the "Simplify geometry" and restarting QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MappaGnosis, I finally found the answer. The problematic dataset was in EPSG:4326 (whereas the rest of the project is in EPSG:3031, but that doesn't really matter). This CRS causes rendering issues near the poles, which seems logical when you think about it.

Reprojecting the dataset in EPSG:3031 (Polar Stereographic) ultimately solved the issue.